# Aligning Nav Menu

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a navigation menu for a website template I'm working on. I want to put the brand name on the left and social media font awesome icons on the right however my brand name is indented while the icons on the right are where they should be. How do I make them even??

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<title>Assignment</title>
<!--Bootstrap For Cleaner Viewability-->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo+Bhaina|PT+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="minimal.css">
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
<div align="center">

<ul id="nav">

<a href="#" id="home">MINIMAL</a> <!--This is the one-->

<a href="#"><li>Home</li></a>
<a href="#"><li>Shop</li></a>
<a href="#"><li>Contact</li></a>
<a href="#"><li>Shop Men</li></a>
<a href="#"><li>Shop Women</li></a>

<a href="#" id="test">MINIMAL</a>

</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#home {
float: left;
padding-top: 15px;
font-size: 30px;
font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
color: #545456;
text-decoration: none;
}

#test  {
float: right;
padding-top: 15px;
font-size: 30px;`enter code here`
font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
color: #545456;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Hi Gabriel, have you given us all of the code we need to have a [mcve] of the problem? The layout doesn't look right, like "the icons on the right are where they should be" - what icons? Your HTML is invalid, too - an `a` can't be a direct child of `ul`

Comment: `#home` is indented because of default CSS for `ul` elements - you should consider examining your page using browser developer tools to see what else is affecting your layout.

Comment: I'm sorry. It looks completely different on my screen. Should I include all scripts and links?

Comment: You should follow @MichaelCoker recommendation and provide us with only the code necessary to repeat the problem within your question.

Comment: @GabrielPozo don't include everything, just the minimum required to reproduce the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers."* See: How to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `li` elements should wrap the link.

To get one on the left and the right, you can do it with floating like so:

```css
#home, #test {
  padding-top: 15px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #545456;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#nav {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
#nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}

#nav li:first-child {
  float: left;
}

#nav li:last-child {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div align="center">

<ul id="nav">

<li><a href="#" id="home">MINIMAL</a></li> <!--This is the one-->

<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Shop Men</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Shop Women</a></li>

<li><a href="#" id="test">MINIMAL</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

---

Or you can use flexbox

```css
#home, #test {
  padding-top: 15px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #545456;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#nav {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}
#nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}

#nav li:first-child {
  margin-right: auto;
}

#nav li:last-child {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div align="center">

<ul id="nav">

<li><a href="#" id="home">MINIMAL</a></li> <!--This is the one-->

<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Shop Men</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Shop Women</a></li>

<li><a href="#" id="test">MINIMAL</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use li for menu items like this:
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abkbkp0u/)

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's only part of the problem, and OP's looking for alignment help with the `#home` element.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for but how i do i set 1 item to be to left and to the right while the others are in the center?